# awscli sync method for boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3, aws-cli

TO copy all files from S3 we are using below awscli command

```
aws s3 sync s3://my-bucket / . --exclude "test-files/*" --region us-east-1
```

Now i want to copy all files in lambda python code using boto3 module.

I am not able to find any method in boto which can do the job of sync.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `sync` command in Boto3. If you still want to do that, you can start a `subprocess` in your code and run `aws s3 sync s3://my-bucket / . --exclude "test-files/*" --region us-east-1`.

I am not sure if `aws-cli` is preinstalled in Lambda Execution environment so you may want to check that first. You can always install it as a dependency.

Comment: Can you me some reference how to install aws-cli in lambda

Comment: `pip install awscli`

Comment: Calling the AWS CLI from an AWS Lambda function is a bit of a hack. The better method would be to write your own code to perform equivalent operations. But, if it works... then go for it!

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code...

```
from concurrent import futures
import os
import boto3

def download_dir(prefix, local, bucket):

    client = boto3.client('s3')

    def create_folder_and_download_file(k):
        dest_pathname = os.path.join(local, k)
        if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(dest_pathname)):
            os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(dest_pathname))
        print(f'downloading {k} to {dest_pathname}')
        client.download_file(bucket, k, dest_pathname)

    keys = []
    dirs = []
    next_token = ''
    base_kwargs = {
        'Bucket': bucket,
        'Prefix': prefix,
    }
    while next_token is not None:
        kwargs = base_kwargs.copy()
        if next_token != '':
            kwargs.update({'ContinuationToken': next_token})
        results = client.list_objects_v2(**kwargs)
        contents = results.get('Contents')
        for i in contents:
            k = i.get('Key')
            if k[-1] != '/':
                keys.append(k)
            else:
                dirs.append(k)
        next_token = results.get('NextContinuationToken')
    for d in dirs:
        dest_pathname = os.path.join(local, d)
        if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(dest_pathname)):
            os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(dest_pathname))
    with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        futures.wait(
            [executor.submit(create_folder_and_download_file, k) for k in keys],
            return_when=futures.FIRST_EXCEPTION,
        )
download_dir('' , 'foldername/path', 'bucket-name')
```

change the prefix according to your need or leave it empty to copy all the files in the bucket.